# How to display layered navigation inside a sticky sidebar in magento CE 1.9

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, layered-navigation

All the category pages are 1column layout. i had created a sticky sidebar in the list.phtml

```
.....
..... 
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="sticky-button">&nbsp;
<div class="sticky">
 // need the layered navigation here
</div>
</div>
```

i had tried :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

definitely this is causing some problems with

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
```

In state.phtml

and it will display(only displays) if i assign $_renderers=null, but its clear that it will not filter any products

[image]

I had commented the `left.nav block in catalog.xml file` as shown below since im using a single column layout.

```
<label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: which magento  are you using?

Comment: @AmitBera magento 1.9 CE

Comment: show left nav catalog.xml code

Comment: @AmitBera question updated with with left/nav code, please note that im using 1column layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution:
My layout for the category page is 1column set with  local.xml

kept catalog.xml unchanged.Reference for the block is still there as shown below:

```
<reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
```

with in my list.phtml i called:

```
<div class="sticky-button">&nbsp;
    <div class="sticky">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had noticed problem with sticky sidebar in search results, because the searchresult dont have the block `catalog.leftnav` hence updated code by::

```
<?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['q'])){
    echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();
    }
else {
    echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalogsearch.leftnav')->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: upvote from me..

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this by layout change at xml

Just change the reference name from `left_first` to `product_list` this `make the layer navigation as  child block  of product list` page .

On **list.phtml** call this block using

```
<?php
    echo $this->getChildHtml('"catalog.leftnav');?>
?>
```

And

**Then xml look like:**

```
<reference name="product_list"><!-- change has been done here -->
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
 </reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, But its not working, no left nav yet

Comment: change catalog.leftnav to my.leftnav

Comment: $this->getChildHtml('my.leftnav');  is not not showing anything

Comment: i had solved it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your local.xml

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

and in list.phml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); ?>
```